# Write text into a file with a loop

Tags: python

I have my name generator that generates names. So I want to open a file "names"
and then write the name into it and save it and loop this process. But it does not work properly. It opens the file and puts one name in and closes it. And then opens it again  and replaces the old word with the new one. But I want that it puts all generated names in it, and saves after it wrote 100 generated words to file. I'm pretty new to it so I don't really know what to do.
Here is my code:

```
import random
import string 
def run_bot():
    x1 = random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase)
    x2 = random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
    x3 = random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
    x4 = random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
    x5 = random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
    name = str(x1 + x2 + x3 +x4 +x5)
    print(name)
    f = open('names', 'w')
    f.write(name)
while True:
for i in range(5):
    run_bot
```

Comment: Use the append mode: `f = open('names', 'a')`. Write mode will overwrite any previous content and add the new one after.

Comment: thanks worked.but do you know a way to write the words among themselves this would make it easier to read them because now they are all in one line without any spaces but thx again :D

Comment: @bot_diyar print(name,file=f)

Comment: @bot_diyar sorry for the delayed answer. You should probably have figured it out by now, but you can do: `f.write(name + '\n')`. Or follow @SmartManoj's advice.

Answer (score 0):

The code with the solutions from the comments.

```
import random
import string 

def generate_name():
    x1 = random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase)
    x2 = random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
    x3 = random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
    x4 = random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
    x5 = random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
    name = str(x1 + x2 + x3 +x4 +x5)
    return name

f = open('names', 'w')
for i in range(5):
    name = generate_name()
    print(name)
    f.write(name + '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter of the `open` function handles in which mode the file will be open.

- 'w' opens the file for writing but truncates the file first
- 'a' opens the file for writing but places the cursor at the end of the file
- 'r' opens the file for reading
- '+' when combined with the other 3, makes it possible to read and write.
- 'b' opens the file in binary mode

In python, it's usually a good practice to use `with` to deal with resource management (in this case, the file handler). It is important because your file will get closed automatically even if some exception happens during the course of the program.

The correct way of implementing it depends on if you want to open and close files multiple times or stay with a file handler open during the whole execution of your program. I'm assuming you really want to just open the file for appending then close and do something else. This may be slower if you're doing it very frequently.

Method 1 (open files multiple times):

```
import random
import string 
def run_bot():
    x1 = random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase)
    x2 = random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
    x3 = random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
    x4 = random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
    x5 = random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
    name = str(x1 + x2 + x3 +x4 +x5)
    print(name)
    with open('names', 'a') as f:
        f.write(name + '\n')
while True:
    for i in range(5):
        run_bot()
```

Method 2 (open file once):

```
import random
import string 
def run_bot(names_file):
    x1 = random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase)
    x2 = random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
    x3 = random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
    x4 = random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
    x5 = random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
    name = str(x1 + x2 + x3 +x4 +x5)
    print(name)
    names_file.write(name + '\n')
    
with open('names', 'a') as fhandler:
    while True:
        for i in range(5):
            run_bot(fhandler)
```